# Only selecting last inserted row from database

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a pop up box that shows when I click on the table row and on that box should be the values from that table row but instead is only showing the last inserted row from db.

Here is the HTML:

```
<tbody>
 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fix_in_time");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `ocorrencia` as o INNER JOIN 
`insere_material` as im ON o.id = im.id");
$num = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
?>
<tr id="table_row_<?php echo $num; ?>" onclick="hide('table_row_<?php echo 
$num; ?>'), window.location= '#bg'">
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['data']; ?> 
</td>
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['sala']; ?> 
</td>
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?> 
</td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<script src="scripts/table.js"></script>
<div id="bg"></div>
<div class="box">
<a href="" id="close">X</a>
<p id="rcorners1"></p>
<p id="Title1">Data</p>
<p id="Title2">Sala</p>
<p id="Title3">Tipo</p>
<p id="Title4">Descrição</p>
<?php
 $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `ocorrencia` as o INNER JOIN `insere_material` as im ON o.id = im.id");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)): ?>
<p class="data"><?php echo $row['data']; ?></p>
<p class="sala"><?php echo $row['sala']; ?></p>
<p class="tipo"><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?></p>
<textarea readonly id="descricao"><?php echo $row['descricao'];?></textarea>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

the pop up click on table row is this:

```
<tr id="table" onclick="hide(), window.location= '#bg'">
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><? php echo $row['data']; ? 
></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['sala']; ?> 
</td>
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?> 
</td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
function hide(tableRow){
var x = document.getElementById(tableRow);
if(x.style.display === "none"){
x.style.display = "block";
}else{
x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

[db table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ciOu.jpg)

[db table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB2R0.jpg)

Comment: can you add screenshot of your both table? and also when you are inner joining tables, it will only fetch record if record exist in both table.

Comment: I can add screenshot but the problem is on my javascript because it is not separating the pop up box values!